# Modify pdf file with right font data for parse text

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdf.js

I'm using `pdf.js` library in NodeJS for parsing text from .pdf files.

But when text is Cyrillic, and there isn't any `ToUnicode` data provided in any of the fonts in this PDF file, then text recognized as English, it mean, that cyrillic letter `П` recognized as english `n` and text becomes unreadible.

Any suggestions to implement fonts to pdf for right parsing?

Comment: If the pdf does not contain the information required for text extraction, don't try text extraction. Try ocr instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I went through converting pdf to image and then extract it.